# Creating points in interval 0.125 decimal degree using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, point

I have a polygon shapefile. I want to create points at an interval of 0.125 decimal degrees in this polygon.

How can I create a script with python in ArcGIS 10 to automate the process of create points?

The start point is the south-west corner and the end point is north-east of the polygon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're interested in additional vertices along your polygon feature, you can use the built-in [Densify function](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000003000000.htm):

```
import arcpy
arcpy.Densify_edit("polygon.shp", "DISTANCE", "0.125")
```

Comment: densify only divide borders of polygon .

Answer (score 6):

You already have your answer; you have your start X/Y and finish X/Y, so you have a range and the distance between the points

Calculate the amount of points you will create per axis

`xRange = maxX - minX`

`yRange= maxY - minY`

`xloop = int(xRange /0.125)+1`

`yloop = int(yRange /0.125)+1`

Create your point variables

`pointGeometryList = []`

`point = arcpy.Point()`

Set the start point

`point.Y = minY`

`point.X = minX`

`for y in range(0,yLoop):

....for x in range(0,xLoop):`

add a point to your point array

`........pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)`

`........pointGeometryList.append(pointGeometry)`

move along the x axis and create a point per 0.125 degrees

`........point.X = point.X + 0.125`

once the xloop has finished, reset X

`....point.X = minX`

and move the yaxis up 0.125

`....point.Y = point.Y + 0.125`

create the point feature

`arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointGeometryList, "c:/geometry/a.gdb/points")`

Please note, this si off the top of my head and completely untested, so I am not responsible for it if you use it.  However, that should, I think, start you off.

You will have created points outside of the polygon, as I have ensured the MBR is properly represented; you may want to erase features outside of the polygon afterwards.

Comment: +1 Whether it works as-is or not, it's a clear, complete account of the algorithm and of the steps needed to make it work in ArcGIS.