# Creating series of points along multiple polylines at once in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, point, line, editing

I have a series of polylines that represent linear vegetation (shelterbelts, etc). I need to convert these to a series of points equally spaced in order to add them to a different shapefile that represents point vegetation (individual trees). I should also mention that I have about 300 polylines to do this to, so would like to be able to do them all at once. The polylines vary in length, but regardless of length, I want to place points at the start at end of each line, and then every 10 m.

I would imagine that this will require python script. Of which I am not familiar with how to write.

Does anyone know how I can do this in ArcMap 10?

I looked at a similar question previously posted for someone who wanted to create 6 points on 70,000 lines of various length and found this python script:

```
import arcpy
points = []
  for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("YourInputLinesFileHere", ["SHAPE@"]):
    length = row[0].length
    for i in range(0,6):
      point = row[0].positionAlongLine(length/5*i)
      points.append(point)    
      arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(points, 'YourOutputPointsFileHere')
```

So I know it must be possible with python but am not familiar with it enough to manipulate this.

Answer (score 6):

Try this in the python window in ArcMap:

```py
points = []
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('C:/Temp/line.shp', ["SHAPE@"]): # change this to your source line layer
    length = int(row[0].length)
    for i in xrange(0, length + 10, 10): # assuming units are in meters for feature spatial reference
        point = row[0].positionAlongLine(i)
        points.append(point)    
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(points, 'C:/Temp/points.shp') # change this to wherever you want this layer stored
```

Comment: This python script also works perfectly - thank you SO much for your help @artwork21

Comment: I am looking to set up a tool that is similar to this script however I would like to place multiple points on a line at specified distances. I have a code working to place a single point on a line, however my python skills are not good enough to figure out how to do it over multiple iterations with different values. Here is the code I'm currently using to place a single point on a line:

Comment: points =[]                                                          with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Line_Feature, ("SHAPE@")) as cursor:
         for row in cursor:
             point.append(row[0].positionAlongLine(float(Distance)))                   
             arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(point, Output)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using the [Construct Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000000n000000) tool while in edit mode.

If you need to do this to multiple features, you could use the [Densify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000) tool, then use the [Feature Vertices to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000).  Keep in mind that this assumes you currently have lines, and not polylines, because ALL vertices (even one's not at your specified densify distance) will also become points.

Also, see [Creating points in interval 0.125 decimal degree using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9761) for a python example to do this process, and [Using 'construct points' on all lines in a shapefile (arcpy)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91287) for a custom tool.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if there is a way to do this to multiple polylines at once? I have almost 300 polylines to do this to.

Comment: probably not able to do it at once but you could iterate through a loop fore each line feature construct the points.

Comment: @Chris R how do you iterate such an operation?

Comment: I've not tested this, but does it work if you select all of the features in the feature class?

Comment: @ew_gis no, once you select more than one polyline, the Construct Points tool is not selectable.

Comment: I don't believe you can call the construct points tool through arcpy.  If that is the case, I can write up a quick densify example.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include links to the Densify and Feature Vertices to Point geoprocesses.  I also added a link to a post that has a decent looking python script.

Comment: @ew_gis that custom tool works PERFECT! Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for finding that - I thought I had looked all over. Thank you again!