# Adding points every 200m along centre line of new road and rail corridors using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

i have Created a point shapefile and want to add points approximately at every 200 m along the centre line of the new road and rail corridors.

after that i want to add field ID to the attribute table and give id to each point.

Comment: So what have you tried, and where do you get stuck? Also add which version of ArcGIS you are using. A screenshot might help explaining as well.

Comment: I answered a question recently that was very similar to yours, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120922/how-to-create-a-series-of-points-along-multiple-polylines-at-once-in-arcmap-10/120942#120942